# Running ASP.NET Web Api 2 application without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing a asp web api 2 webservice for a private project.
I created a webservice-project which includes all the folder (App_Data,App_Start,Controllers,...) and all my classes/functionallity.

Now I would like to run it as a selfhosted windows service or from command line to test all the functionallity without running Visual Studio.

All I found was a tutorial how to create a new command-line programm and create a new webservice (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) ....
But how can I just selfhost my created webservice-project and use its WebApiConfig??

**UPDATE 1**

at least I found out how to start the IISExpress from CommandLine to test my webservice without VisualStudio:
I had to run this:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /config:"C:\Users\Tobias\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" /site:MyWebservicename
```

Comment: So do you still have a question? Or did you just answer it yourself?

Comment: yes I answered my question.

Comment: Just as a remark, maybe helpful for other people: I was trying to achieve the same but by using the /path:[...] option, which did not work as expected. The solution was quite simple but unintuitive: **the path you provide in as /path argument needs to be the _parent_ folder of the 'bin' folder in which your compiled WebApi binaries lie.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try that

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /config:"C:\Users\Tobias\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config" /site:MyWebservicename
```