# Command to publish Web API developed in C# .net framework 4.6

Tags: c#, command, asp.net-web-api2, publish, .net-4.6

I have Web API developed in C# and .Net framework 4.6.

I have hosted it on a server in IIS and it is working fine. Whenever there is any change, I change the code, do the testing and publish it.

The publishing is done manually till now. The process which we follow is, right click on API project, select `Publish`, select Publish Method as `File System`,Target Location as `Some path on local machine`, Configuration as `Release` and click on Publish button.It generates a set of files in the target location. I will copy those set of files on to the server.

Now I want to automate this process. So for this I'm writing commands to do this. So for building the application, I'm using MSBuild.exe.

```
MSBuild.exe ProjectName.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

For publishing I have used this command :

```
dotnet.exe publish ProjectName.sln /p:configuration=Release
```

But when I run this publish command, it is giving :

> Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to
> restore.

So I have following questions:

1. Why is it trying to restoring packages when I'm trying to publish. I'm already restoring packages using another command before building --> `Nuget.exe restore ProjectName.sln`. So I do not want it to restore anything.
2. Am I using the correct command to publish. If yes, how do I specify the target location?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using .Net core. Hence dotnet command will not work.

The **dotnet** command line would work only with asp.net core projects.

Alternative :

Please [refer this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765029/running-asp-net-web-api-2-application-without-visual-studio) which shows how to run web api2 project using command line:

Hope this helps.